# Is there a look-ahead bias in the following code?

Tags: python, trading

Hi first of all im new on stack overflow and this is my first question

i want to know where in the following code is look-ahead bias is happening i rewrote the code as shown below but still wont get any entry trades is there any way to to just look at the past trend and determine the trend without looking at the next candles

```
import numpy as np
from statistics import mean


def support(df, index, n1, n2, col):
    for i in range(index - n1 + 1, index + 1):
        if(df[col][i] > df[col][i - 1]):
            return False
    for i in range(index + 1, index + n2 + 1):
        if(df[col][i] < df[col][i - 1]):
            return False
    return True


def is_Support_Level(df, i):
    return support(df, i, 2, 2, 'low')


def is_Resistance_Level(df, i):
    return support(df, i, 2, 2, 'high')


def find_levels(n):
    if n > 1:
        return n.round(2)

    s = '{:.20f}'.format(n % 1)
    zeros = (len(s) - len(s.lstrip('0.').lstrip('0')))
    return n.round(zeros + 1)


def support_resistance(df, dataframe):

    levels = []
    mean = np.mean(df['high'] - df['low'])
    # This function, given a price value, returns True or False depending on if it
    # is too near to some previously discovered key level.

    def distance_from_mean(level, levels):
        return np.sum([abs(level - y) < mean for y in levels]) == 0

    supports = []
    resistances = []
    for i in range(2, df.shape[0] - 2):
        if is_Support_Level(df, i):
            level = find_levels(df['low'][i])
            if distance_from_mean(level, levels):
                levels.append(level)
                supports.append(level)

        elif is_Resistance_Level(df, i):
            level = find_levels(df['high'][i])
            if distance_from_mean(level, levels):
                levels.append(level)
                resistances.append(level)

    supports.sort()
    for i in range(11):
        s = len(supports) - i - 1
        r = len(resistances) - i - 1

        support = "s" + str(i + 1)
        resistance = "r" + str(i + 1)
        dataframe[support] = supports[s] if s >= 0 else np.nan
        dataframe[resistance] = resistances[r] if r >= 0 else np.nan


# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

def get_up_trend(results):
    up_trends = list()
    for up in results['Up Trend']:
        flag = True

        for down in results['Down Trend']:
            if down['from'] < up['from'] < down['to'] or down['from'] < up['to'] < down['to']:
                if (up['to'] - up['from']) > (down['to'] - down['from']):
                    flag = True
                else:
                    flag = False
            else:
                flag = True

        if flag is True:
            up_trends.append(up)
    return up_trends


def get_down_trend(results):
    down_trends = list()
    for down in results['Down Trend']:
        flag = True

        for up in results['Up Trend']:
            if up['from'] < down['from'] < up['to'] or up['from'] < down['to'] < up['to']:
                if (up['to'] - up['from']) < (down['to'] - down['from']):
                    flag = True
                else:
                    flag = False
            else:
                flag = True

        if flag is True:
            down_trends.append(down)
    return down_trends


def identify_df_trends(df, column, window_size=5):
    objs = list()
    df['Trend'] = 0

    up_trend = {
        'name': 'Up Trend',
        'element': np.negative(df[column])
    }

    down_trend = {
        'name': 'Down Trend',
        'element': df[column]
    }

    objs.append(up_trend)
    objs.append(down_trend)
    results = dict()

    for obj in objs:
        limit = None
        values = list()
        trends = list()

        from_trend = 0
        for index, value in enumerate(obj['element'], 0):
            if limit and limit > value:
                values.append(value)
                limit = mean(values)
            elif limit and limit < value:
                if len(values) > window_size:
                    min_value = min(values)

                    for counter, item in enumerate(values, 0):
                        if item == min_value:
                            break

                    to_trend = from_trend + counter

                    trend = {
                        'from': df.index.tolist()[from_trend],
                        'to': df.index.tolist()[min(to_trend, len(df.index.tolist()) - 1)],
                    }

                    trends.append(trend)

                limit = None
                values = list()
            else:
                from_trend = index
                values.append(value)
                limit = mean(values)

        results[obj['name']] = trends

    up_trends = get_up_trend(results)
    for up_trend in up_trends:
        for index, row in df[up_trend['from']:up_trend['to']].iterrows():
            df.loc[index, 'Trend'] = 1

    down_trends = get_down_trend(results)
    for down_trend in down_trends:
        for index, row in df[down_trend['from']:down_trend['to']].iterrows():
            df.loc[index, 'Trend'] = -1

    return df
```

i rewrote the the support function but still no entries were made

```
def support(df, index, n1, n2, col):
    for i in range(index - n1, index): # changes made
        if(df[col][i] > df[col][i - 1]):
            return False
    for i in range(index + 1, index + n2 + 1):
        if(df[col][i] < df[col][i - 1]):
            return False
    return True
```